# Magento 2 customer is saved as guest even if he logged-in in quote table

Tags: checkout, addtocart, sales-quote

We have an issue that if a customer is logged-in and add product to cart, in quote table we have a column as `customer_is_guest`, it is saving as 1, even if the customer is logged-in, it is showing as guest. Due to this case, we are getting an error as "Invalid customer addresses id". We have upgraded magento from 2.2.6 to 2.2.8. Is there any solution for that? Please let me know.

Comment: I'm getting the same error - did you ever get around to resolving this?

Comment: hii daniel, did you have any recent upgradation of magento.Can i know what's the exact  scenario the issue is coming.